# Best practices in creating Cordova plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm still starting to create a Cordova plugin, I've read their [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide/plugin-development/) and an [article](http://www.mat-d.com/site/tutorial-creating-a-cordova-phonegap-plugin-for-android-app/) on how to create one.
I found it simple and easy to create however, aside from creating I would like to know if what are the best practices and/or useful tools to be used for debugging and testing the plugin. Also what would the best OOP Javascript pattern to implement?

Thanks!

Comment: start by reading the latest documentation, the one you linked is very old https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

Comment: thanks, just have read the documentation on the link provided, but still the content is almost similar with the one I've found.

Comment: yeah, it's similar, but some important things changed and if you don't read them it won't work and you will ask why